# Firebase database not a function error in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I keep getting a `firebase.database()` is not a function error when trying to use firebase from a reactjs app

Here is how I am initializing my firebase from a file called **Firebase.js**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        this.firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
}

export default Firebase;
```

Here is my **FirebaseContext.js** file

```
import React from "react";

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const FirebaseProvider = FirebaseContext.Provider;
export default FirebaseContext;
```

Now in my **index.js** file I have this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from './pages/App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Firebase from "./backend/configs/firebase";
import {FirebaseProvider} from "./contexts/FirebaseContext";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <FirebaseProvider value={new Firebase()}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </FirebaseProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now, if I call the firebase object in one of my Functional Components like this

```
import FirebaseContext from "../contexts/FirebaseContext";
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Dashboard() {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
    firebase
        .database()   //Firebase is not a function error happens here
        .ref("updates")
        .once('value')
        .then(function (snapshot) {
        });
}
```

In my Dashboard Component above I keep getting errors that firebase.database() is not a function.Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how it should look like :

```
const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
```

Comment: OMG! I deserve to be FIRED!!! Lolz...Thanks alot. It has finally worked.

Comment: how about the usage in a class component, any idea?

Comment: I think you can try something like this : `static contextType = FirebaseContext; const { firebase } = this.context`